What is "B & S" a reference to in Khartoum?
In the 1966 film Khartoum, starring Charlton Heston, there's a brief aside by Gordon after accepting the Governorship of Sudan (about 34 minutes into the film). (Sorry, but I can't find a link to this moment in the film.)
After negotiating his fee downwards, Gordon turns to his aide, Colonel Stewart, as he's leaving the room and says, "What about the B & S?"
What is this a reference to? I can't find any suitable meaning of B & S either to the era the film was shot (1960s) or the era the film was about (1880s Egypt).
It appears to be an inconsequential aside, but I really can't get the meaning.

This site suggests the line is "a B&S", in which case, brandy and soda?

@AakashM - looks like I mis-heard the original line. Thanks for the link to that website - very useful

I thought I heard, “how about ‘that’ B & S” and it made sense at the time, my first viewing back in the 60’s. That was an impressive film - well it made a lasting impression on me. I understood it a bit better on later viewings

It's "Brandy and Soda".
There is a line a few minutes earlier

Brandy and soda, sir.
B & S? It sounds as though you'll need one.


Considered to be quite a fancy cocktail of the glittering young people in the mid-war period; https://www.masterofmalt.com/blog/post/cocktail-of-the-week-the-brandy-and-soda.aspx/#:~:text=The%20Brandy%20and%20Soda%2C%20or,%E2%80%9CSir%3F%E2%80%9D

@Valorum - my mother (born 1920) and her sister my aunt (5 years older) both liked brandy and soda, but my father said it was a 'woman's drink'.

I cannot think of a single father who doesn't denigrate at least one mixed drink as a woman's drink. It is dad-speak for " I don't care for it"

@Yorik "women's drinks" are fruity or too sweet, quite possibly with a little umbrella in them.  Chardonnay, too. A Real Man's drink is bitter or tastes like medicine; Scotch, for example.

@RonJohn When it comes to cocktails, I take 'soda' to mean carbonated water. So I would expect it to be brandy and water that happens to be fizzy.  Not really a sweet drink and honestly, I wonder if people who don't put at least a little water in their brandy or whiskey have any working taste buds.

@JimmyJames - I am a confirmed drinker of single-malt Scotch whisky (spelled thus) and I don't add water to the bottled kind available retail in the UK. I note that it has already been diluted down from cask strength. I've tried the ritual of a drop or two with cask strength whisky but I can't say it made a lot of difference to me personally.

@MichaelHarvey Sorry, it was meant as a light-hearted jab at the idea that adding water makes liquor less masculine (but often. somehow ice is OK.) As you note, water is already added by the producer in most bottles. Personally, I never really enjoyed whiskey or brandy until I started adding water. The right amount is when it tastes good for the drinker. I noticed that the recipe calls for bitters which might be something I would try with a cheap brandy.
